# phpgrid - change edit route

Tags: php, phpgrid

I am using [phpgrid](https://phpgrid.com) in a Slim Framework integration and I see all the editing and creating functionality of the phpgrid system sends the data to a file called "edit.php" that sits inside the phpgrid folder.

Is there any way that I can change that and actually route the result of the form to a different file, preferably a controller in Slim?

**L.E:** It's worth to mention that I am not using a DB connection to process the data. Instead, I use an API to fetch and process my data, and I feed the data to phpgrid in an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seams that on closer inspection to the documentation, somewhere hidden without the ability to clearly search for it, there is a method called: [set_js_editurl()](https://phpgrid.com/documentation/set_jq_editurl/).

This method lets you set your own URL and everything else works the same :)

Happy coding,
Ares D.

Answer (score 1):

Google "phpgrid save local array" gives this post

[Save Local Data Array Back to Server via Ajax](https://phpgrid.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/359814-save-local-data-array-back-to-server-via-ajax)

You can use submit the changes in jQuery ajax post to whatever url of your choice

[Demo](https://phpdatagrid.com/examples/phpGridx/examples/local_array.php)

```
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>
<form id="admin_form">
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit Local Changes">
    </div>
</form>

<script>
    $(function() {
        // bind to the form's submit event
        $('#admin_form').submit(function(event) {
            $(this).ajaxSubmit({
                type: 'post',
                dataType:'json',
                url:'save_local_array.php',
                data:{
                    langArray:[] //leave as empty array here
                },
                beforeSubmit: function(arr, $form, options){
                    options.langArray = $('#data1').jqGrid('getRowData'); //current
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(options.langArray));
                    // return false; // here to prevent submit
                },
                success: function(){
                    // add routine here when success
                }
            });

            // return false to prevent normal browser submit and page navigation
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```